# I need help making a program in python that turns an integer into 8-bit binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive been give a task, it is as follows:

**write a function called decToBin that takes in an integer and converts it to an 8-bit binary number represented as a string**

As I am new to this im very lost! Having no introduction to my task as thrown me off a little and I really need some help!

I have tried the following code:

```
#function
def decTobin(integer)
    return bin

#main program
decToBin(3)
decToBin(4)
decToBin(5)
```

However I had no sucess, could someone point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please, first try going through any Python tutorial.

Comment: `dec2bin = lambda x: '%08d' %int(bin(x)[2:]) if isinstance(x, int) else '0'*8`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `decToBin = "{:08b}".format` is shorter!

Comment: Based on your three frankly terrible questions so far I agree with @Christian that you should review some introductory tutorials (e.g. [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html)). You should also talk to your teacher. What you have so far makes no sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have been looking at inroductory tutorials for the pas 10 hours or so, and ive gotten stuck on this task. I agree with "You should also talk to your teacher" because I would, only is 11pm during a school holiday. "What you have so far makes no sense." Yes I know I probabbly makes no sense, im still very new to the language, and I have been reading bits of code from the internet and trying them to see if they would work.

Comment: @user3142463: Your post in its current form, looks like it was assigned to you for homework. Coupled with no visible effort from your end, it doesn't fit the format of questions for this site. Hence the comment. If you would like to edit into your post, your previous attempts, errors thereof, divergences in observed and expected behavior, you'd get much better responses. As it stands, I have no idea what you're having trouble with. It doesn't even look like you've run the code, so I'm at a loss of how to help, but I did post up a solution for you in my first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to keep your questions tidy. Also, judging from your other questions, you should look at some basic python tutorials. Happy coding!

Try to learn about base conversions. [Here](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~scott/teaching/2008/spring/384/handouts/decimal-binary.pdf) is a great place to find a step by step walkthrough for doing it manually.

You will need to use the modulo (%) operator. The modulo operator is a binary operator, meaning it has two inputs. You use it like so:

```
a % b
```

It returns the remainder when a is divided by b:

```
10 % 7 = 3
```

The following code will do what you need:

```
def decToBin(x):
    if x == 0:
        return "00000000"
    bits = []
    while x:
        bits.append(str(x % 2))
        x >>= 1
    return "".join(bits).zfill(8)
```

I will explain line by line.

```
def decToBin(x):
```

This declares the function.

```
if x == 0:
    return "00000000"
```

This returns a string of eight zeros if the input is zero. We need this because the while loop only operates when x is not equal to zero.

```
bits = []
```

This initializes the array of bits. During the while loop, we will add to this with the append function.

```
while x:
```

This begins a while loop, which runs until x is false (or zero).

```
bits.append(str(x % 2))
```

This adds to the bits array the remainder when x is divided by 2. str() converts it to a string.

```
x >>= 1
```

>>= 1 Shifts the bits in x to the right one time like so:

```
Before: 1 1 0 1 0 1
After:  0 1 1 0 1 0
```

It is the same as dividing by 2, without keeping the remainder.

```
return "".join(bits).zfill(8)
```

Breakdown:

```
"abc".join(l)
```

Joins all the strings in list l, separating it with abc.

```
"2345".zfill(i)
```

adds zeros to the beginning of a string until there are i numbers. So

```
return "".join(bits).zfill(8)
```

returns the array of bits as one string, and pads the beginning until there are eight characters.

Comment: @user3142463 Please try to understand the math. I know I didn't include an explanation, but you would gain much from it.